# Limit buffer in read() function

Tags: c

I have to create a program that asks from standard input a string and write in standard error the string previously written.
This is my program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>

 int main() {
    char *buffer = malloc(sizeof(char)*20);
    int len = 0;

    do {
        len = read(STDIN_FILENO, buffer, 20);
        if(len == -1)
            write(STDERR_FILENO, "Error read\n", 10);
        else
            write(STDERR_FILENO, buffer, len);
    } while(strncmp(buffer,"fine\n", 5));

    free(buffer);
    return 0;
}
```

The code works but I'm not satisfied..there is one problem:
The buffer is a 20char but I can insert more than 20 char...why? How I can limit the buffer to only 20 char?

Comment: What __exactly__ is the requirement? You could limit the length of the string to some fairly big number (e.g. 4000) which is reasonable, because text files rarely have vewry long lines. I also suggest not to use `read` and `write` but `fread` and `fwrite`, or even `fgets` if the input is line oriented.

Comment: Note: `strlen(`"Error read\n")` is 11, not 10.

Comment: I don't think you can "insert" (read) more than 20 chars. `read` just stops at your buffer size.

Comment: i have to use read and write..it's not my chose

Comment: There are plenty of ways to achieve what you want. Simple if validation statement to limit 20 char can solve your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The code works but I'm not satisfied..there is one problem: The buffer is a 20char but I can insert more than 20 char...why?

Because your program can't stop someone inputting more than 20 chars; all it can do is *limit* that it doesn't overflow the `buffer` which it already does - `read()` doesn't read more than the requested bytes. It only *appears* as if a `read()` call is reading more than size (20) but acutally read() reads only (upto) 20 chars and the rest is read in the *next* iteration.

No matter what method you use to read input and/or increase buffer size, this problem of "extra input" is always going to be there.
What you can do instead is check if if `len` is 20 *and* `buffer[19]` is not `\n`:

```
   else {
        write(STDERR_FILENO, buffer, len);
        /* Read out the left over chars. */
        if (len == 20 && buffer[19] != '\n') {
            char c;
            do {
                read(STDIN_FILENO, &c, 1); /* left out the error checking */
            } while (c != '\n');
        }
```

Or increase the buffer size, say, to 512 bytes and then only look at the first 20 bytes that you're interested in.

Note: Add error checking for *all* `read()` and `write()` calls.

Comment: Ok, I have implemented your first solution but I have some questions: You check if the input is more than (19 char + \n). If yes, what does that read(STDIN_FILENO, &c, 1); ? I mean.. if I will not insert the endline command, what will happen? I don't see any problem but I don't know why

Comment: `read(STDIN_FILENO, &c, 1);` reads a single byte (and is discarded). If you don't enter a newline, your program won't get an input at all (also [see](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Canonical-or-Not.html)).

Answer (score 0):

You're not allocating enough memory for your buffer. You always need 1 more to store the NUL terminating character. And you also need to remember to add that NUL character to the end of the string read in by `read` as it won't do it for you.

When you get an error, you should exit the loop.

```
#define BUF_SIZE (20)
int main() {
    char *buffer = malloc(sizeof(char)*(BUF_SIZE+1));
    int len = 0;

    do {
        len = read(STDIN_FILENO, buffer, BUF_SIZE);
        if(len == -1) {
            write(STDERR_FILENO, "Error read\n", 10);
            break;
        } else {
            buffer[len]='\0';
            write(STDERR_FILENO, buffer, len);
        }
    } while(strncmp(buffer,"fine\n", 5));

    free(buffer);
    return 0;
}
```

You'll probably also find that the `strncmp(buffer,"fine\n", 5)` isn't going to work as you'd need to process the read in string to handle lines of input as `read` will happily read in multiple lines at a time (assuming they all fit in the buffer size).